# Xcode code signing identity gets a "permission denied" error when trying to sign a kext target

Tags: xcode, code-signing, kernel-extension

In my target build settings for a kext, I put my developer cert (with the new kext signing permissions) in the `Code Signing Identity` key.

However, when build the kext target, I get an error saying that permission is denied for the target.

It appears it succeeds to build the kext, but when it tries to sign it afterwards it doesn't have permission.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a custom build step (shell script?) in your project that changes the ownership and permissions of the kext to root. I recommend copying the kext instead (after the signing step, and after deleting any existing such copy) and then changing the owner of the copy, not the original.

Comment: Exactly right!  I found out my stupid mistake yesterday but haven't closed the thread.  Thanks for answering my questions, by the way :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad you got it all sorted in the end!